Is there a proxy to distribute flink metrics into different pushgateway instance?
In fink-conf.yaml, there only one pushgateway could set, when sigle flink conf file is used by throunds of flink task, the one pushgateway will crash due to memory out of limit. So, is there a way that i can config a proxy in flink-conf.yaml to distribute the push metric stress into multip pg instances.
If there a proxy achieve the goal above, a potential requirement is when a flink task startup, which pg instance it have push some metrics data need to keep associate with this pg instance until shutdown. Otherwise, the prometheus series will be discontinuity because the label value is different.
This main requirement is single pg instance can only revcieve approximately 100 pg group in flink metric.
I have trying depolyed a nginx serve as the role of proxy, but the prometheus series is discontinuity because the label instance is different
